# ¿Cómo funciona internamente el tipado dinamico? (dynamic type)

Tags: arquitectura, compilador

> **Notas:**
>
> - No estoy preguntando cuáles son las diferencias entre el tipado dinámico (dynamically typed) y el tipado estático (statically typed),
>     ya sean ventajas o desventajas.

¿Alguien me puede decir como funciona el tipado dinámico en relación con el gestor de memoria?

Cómo trabaja el gestor de memoria (o la parte encargada) de decidir si necesita otra dirección de memoria etc. (para almacenar los datos), creándola o ampliando la actual si es posible (especulación) etc.

Por ejemplo (especulación): cuando la variable `x = 5` es inicializada y a esta se le asigina `x = "dynamically"`, la parte `Z` del gestor, verifica que se cuenta con el espacio para el nuevo tipo, y actúa en consecuencia, reservando una nueva dirección de memoria para el nuevo tipo y asignándole la nueva dirección a la variable inicial. Esto es una especulación porque no sé cómo funciona exactamente "sé que existirán diferentes implementaciones para lo mismo" dependiendo del intérprete/compilador/etc.

Lo que me gustaría saber es la idea general de `Z` -> intérprete/compilador/etc. y el código encargado de tal tarea.

He mirado algunos proyectos, entre ellos el [V8 de Google](https://github.com/v8/v8), pero no es un proyecto pequeño y no he podido encontrar la parte en la que se trata tal asunto, para así deducir cuál es la idea de cómo funciona `Z` para el caso de `V8`.

La respuesta no tiene por qué ser en base a `V8` puede ser sobre otro lenguaje, intérprete etc, lo que me interesa es la idea de cómo funciona en x caso, o en la mayoría de los casos, (pero no una especulación sobre cómo funciona), y si es posible me gustaría una referencia a la parte del código que refleja la idea expuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible implementación, en C, de una `variable` del lenguaje Javascript:

```
enum VarialeType {
  Undefined = 0,
  Nil,
  Bool,
  String,
  Number,
  Array,
  Object
};

struct String {
  size_t length;
  size_t alloc;
  int ref_count; // Contador de referencias, para liberar la memória.
  char value[];
};

struct Object {
  int ref_count;
  ...
};

struct Array {
  int ref_count;
  ...
};

struct Variable {
  int type;
  struct Object *scope; // Ámbito de la variable. Similar a un Object.
                        // También podría considerar como su "padre".
  union {
    struct String *str;
    double number;
    struct Array *array;
    struct Object *object;
  };
};
```

- Los tipos *primitivos* (usados y pasados por valor) se almacenan en la propia variable.
- Los tipos *complejos* se almacenan como punteros a los datos internos de dichos tipos.

Sin perder lo anterior de vista, es *relativamente* fácil imaginar el proceso para cambiar dinamicamente de tipo:

- Si los tipos son iguales, no pasa nada.
- Si los tipos no son iguales, miramos en una tabla de tipos compatibles, para ver que operación hay que realizar.
- Creamos una nueva variable, con el tipo deseado, para *contener* el nuevo tipo. El *tiempo de vida* de dicha variable está limitado a la expresión en la que se use, pero el proceso de crearla no tiene en cuenta esto.

El último punto implica que cada variable ha de tener un *scope*, un contenedor, un *ambito*, que limita su tiempo de vida.

También implica que la variable original **no cambia**, salvo al hacerle una asignación.

Si **asignamos** un nuevo valor a la variable, pues depende. Si es un *primitivo* (por valor), se cambia y listo.

Si es *complejo*, hariamos -1 al contador de referencias, y comprobariamos si el número de referencias `== 0`, con lo que podriamos liberar la memoria.

El tema del conteo de referencias ... es **complicado**, y yo mismo no estoy seguro de entenderlo del todo ...

Para lenguajes **interpretados**, da *relativamente* igual el usar tipado dinámico o estático; al final, vamos a buscar en una tabla *hash* la variable, y crearla en el *heap*; ya puestos, nos da igual reservar un bloque de memoria de 20 o de 100 *bytes* (técnicas de optimización de reserva de memoria aparte).

En lenguajes **compilados**, la cosa cambia. Una variable es un *alias* para una dirección de memoria concreta; buscando la mayor velocidad, dicha dirección de memoria es **fija** durante todo el tiempo de ejecución del programa ... *ergo* **no podemos cambiar el tamaño de dicho bloque**; por lo tanto, no podemos cambiar el tipo.

**Existen** lenguajes *compilados* que soportan un gran *dinamismo*, aunque *hacen trampa*: para variables que puedan cambiar de tipo, las crean **siempre** en el *heap*, y acceden mediante un puntero. Te recomiendo echarle una ojeada al código fuente de `libobjc`, la librería de soporte en tiempo de ejecución de Objective-C (viene con los fuentes del `gcc`); en su versión `2.xx` no lo se, pero la versión `1.x` es mágnifica para aprender sobre tipos dinámicos compilados.

Hasta aquí llegamos ... por ahora. Espero comentarios para extenderme (en la medida de lo posible) sobre algún tema concreto ... hasta que cierren la pregunta ;-)